# Highcharts piechart with slice animation and drilldown on click together throws exception in chart and breaks the pie chart

Tags: highcharts, click, mouseover, pie-chart, drilldown

I have a pie chart [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjargaurav/5H675/2/). On click event it drills down and on mouseover it does the slice animation. The slice animation is copied from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669757/highcharts-pie-chart-return-slice-animation-on-mouseout) from Pawel Fus

The events I have on pie chart point are as below,

```
mouseOut: function () {
    setTranslation(this, false);
},
mouseOver: function() {
    setTranslation(this, true);
},
click: function() {
    var drilldown = this.drilldown;
    if (drilldown) { // drill down
        setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
    } else { // restore
        setChart(name, categories, data);
    }
}
```

and the functions used in them are

```
function setChart(name, categories, data, color) {
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    chart.series[0].remove();
    chart.addSeries({
        name: name,
        data: data,
        pointPadding: -0.3,
        borderWidth: 0,
        pointWidth: 15,
        shadow: false,
        color: color || 'white'
    });
}

function setTranslation(p, slice){
    p.sliced = slice;
    if(p.sliced){
        p.graphic.animate(p.slicedTranslation);
    } else {
        p.graphic.animate({
            translateX: 0,
            translateY: 0
        });
    }
}
```

The problem I have is it throws following exception:

`Uncaught TypeError: Property 'select' of object #<Object> is not a function highcharts.src.js:12364`

It breaks the chart when clicking on it for drilldown.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I guess the mouseover event is getting messed up on drilldown.

It would be great if I can get both these features working together.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with actual running animation. I advice to not use setting translation to a pie chart until all animations for a slice are don, see: http://jsfiddle.net/5H675/5/

```
function setTranslation(p, slice) {
    p.sliced = slice;
    if (!$(p.graphic).is(':animated')) {
        if (p.sliced) {
            p.graphic.animate(p.slicedTranslation);
        } else {
            p.graphic.animate({
                translateX: 0,
                translateY: 0
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Pawel it seems to be working but with a problem that if you hover over multiple slices there are more than two slices which are sliced. However I would only want one slice to be sliced out at any given point just try [the sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5H675/6/) and hover over green slice and then red.

Comment: Yes, this is how it works from the beginning. You cna disable animation, and use `attr()` function instead, see: http://jsfiddle.net/5H675/7/